# FreeBSD Established Connections Maxing out at 300

Tags: freebsd, tcp, kernel, connections

We've previously had issues in our environment where it seemed we were reaching FreeBSDs max connection limit. We took action demonstrated by http://nginx.org/en/docs/freebsd_tuning.html and bumped up our connections limit to 500: kern.ipc.somaxconn: 500

We're still having issues where we expect to see additional connections from clients to this particular server and we are not, they're missing.

We don't know whether this is an application issue or a networking issue. But I was wondering if there is some other limit we're hitting now, maybe with max number of established connections?

Here's some graphs showing our connection behavior which looks strangely like it's limited at 300 connections:

[image: Connections to the aforementioned box]
[image: Missing Commands]

Approximate number of missing commands on our server ^

EDIT: 
Additional details about the application: The application is a tclsh (tcl shell) listening on a specific tcp port using the socket application to receive connections. Maybe this is some tcl-based limitation or a socket application limit?

Troubleshooting Details:
When I run nmap to basically "ping" the desired port over and over again

```
for i in {1..600}; do nmap -p 2069 serverIP; done
```

I seem to get the following with netstat:

```
netstat -Lan | grep 2069
tcp4  193/0/128      *.2069
tcp4  193/0/128      *.2069
tcp4  193/0/128      *.2069
tcp4  193/0/128      *.2069
```

This seems to mean that I am actually maxing out kern.ipc.somaxconn defaults. But we have already set that value to much higher than the default.

Even when I monitor established connections using:

```
netstat -an | grep 2069 | wc -l
```

I only get a grand total of 192 connections on 2069. Meaning it's not accepting more on that particular port.

Comment: I would use a benchmarking tool like apachebench (ab) to first determine if there is actually a limit you are hitting.  I would also take tcpdumps of the traffic during this time to see what's actually happening.  You'll have to determine the cause before you can find a proper solution.

Comment: I'm just wondering if there is any other inherit limits with max number of free connections or some other kind of network/tcp limits I might be hitting. Debugging this particular application is not very easy like it would be with apache as it is an in-house custom piece of software that infrastructure team does not have ownership of.

Comment: It's most likely application scalability issue not connected to kernel.

Comment: I suspect this, but I'm not familiar enough with kernel limits to definitively say so. Any good methods of proving this? How can I easily open additional established connections and prove it to be an application issue?

Comment: Additional details about the application: The application is a tclsh (tcl shell) listening on a specific tcp port using the socket application to receive connections. Maybe this is some tcl-based limitation or a socket application limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it was actually an application limit. The process listening on the 2069 socket was built with a max number of 192 listen connections.

I'm assuming a lot of applications are built like with these limits in place and its likely that somaxconn just increases total allowable listening sockets vs what the application is actually built for.

Answer (score 0):

File handles come to my mind. First check with `ulimit -n` (or, depending on the shell, `limit -n`) if it returns `1024`. If it does, bump up the file handle limit with `ulimit -n 16384`, `limit -n 16384` or so. See if that helps.

Comment: Doesn't look like a file handle limit. Looks like a connections per socket limit.